# remote open/close jalousie windows

Tags: windows, home-automation

In Hawaii it's very common to have jalousie windows with a turn crank to open and close the slats. I'm looking for a device that will allow me to wirelessly turn the crank to open and close the windows. So far I've only found devices that push and pull instead of turn. My eventual plan is to connect rain sensors to automatically decide when the windows should be closed if I'm sleeping.

Has anyone else done this or something similar?

Comment: Good news is that the crank rotates and electric motors rotate so it's just a matter of gearing and a bracket to hold it together.  That said, I'm not aware of a pre-made solution.

Comment: Maybe this is a good excuse to buy a 3D printer!